# Undefined control sequence \bbljan

Tags: bibliographies, babel

I'm writing a bibliography for an article in Russian. Using `\bibliographystyle{plain}` is not an option, since it uses e.g. conjunction "and" when listing authors. So I'm sticking to `\bibliographystyle{ugost2008}`, but it keeps complaining that `\bbljan` is undefined. I assume that `\bbljan` should expand to "January" for English and to "Январь" for Russian. My `babel` apparently doesn't know anything about `\bbljan` though. I'm currently using

```
\def\bbljan{Январь}
```

but isn't it lame? What should I do?

Comment: I tried finding whether `\bbljan` is defined somewhere, but I didn't find any place. Can you work out a complete, but minimal, example?

Comment: Is there `\bbljan` in your bibfile?

Answer (score 7):

The `\bbljan` macro is set up in `merlin.mbs`, the master file for creating BibTeX styles with the `custom-bib` system. Thus you find `\bbljan` mainly in `.bst` files created this way. Presumably, the author of `ugost2008` used `custom-bib` but then removed the part that sets up `\bbljan` (*etc.*) for some reason. The work-around is to define these yourself, as you've done, but ideally the `.bst` file should be fixed either to define the macros correctly or not to use them at all.

Answer (score 4):

My preamble holds next definitions

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\bibliographystyle{ugost2008ns}
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
\newfontfamily\russianfont{Times New Roman}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

and i have same problem with `\bbljan`, `\bblfeb`, ... functions.

First, i done some rewrite `ugost2008ns` which located in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/gost/ugost2008ns.bst`

I replace all `\bbl*` functions to another which executes right in `ugost2008ns`

```
MACRO {jan} {"jan"}
MACRO {feb} {"feb"}
MACRO {mar} {"mar"}
MACRO {apr} {"apr"}
MACRO {may} {"may"}
MACRO {jun} {"jun"}
MACRO {jul} {"jul"}
MACRO {aug} {"aug"}
MACRO {sep} {"sep"}
MACRO {oct} {"oct"}
MACRO {nov} {"nov"}
MACRO {dec} {"dec"}
```

Here is my new `format.date` function which implements those `\bbl*`

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year empty$
    { month empty$
        { "" }
        { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$
          month
        }
      if$}
    { curlanguage "russian" =
         { month empty$
            { year }
            { month "jan" =
                { year "\cyrya\cyrn\cyrv." }
            { month "feb" =
                { year "\cyrf\cyre\cyrv\cyrr." }
            { month "mar" =
                { year "\cyrm\cyra\cyrr\cyrt" }
            { month "apr" =
                { year "\cyra\cyrp\cyrr." }
            { month "may" =
                { year "\cyrm\cyra\cyrishrt" }
            { month "jun" =
                { year "\cyri\cyryu\cyrn\cyrsftsn" }
            { month "jul" =
                { year "\cyri\cyryu\cyrl\cyrsftsn" }
            { month "aug" =
                { year \cyra\cyrv\cyrg\. }
            { month "sep" =
                { year "\cyrs\cyre\cyn\cyrt." }
            { month "oct" =
                { year "\cyro\cyrk\cyrt." }
            { month "nov" =
                { year "\cyrn\cyro\cyrya\cyrb." }
            { month "dec" =
                { year "\cyrd\cyre\cyrk." }
            { year "Nomember" }
            if$}if$}if$}if$}if$}if$}if$}if$}if$}if$}if$}if$}if$}
         { month empty$
            { year }
            { month "jan" =
               { year "Jan." }
            { month "feb" =
               { year "Feb." }
            { month "mar" =
               { year "Mar." }
            { month "apr" =
               { year "Apr." }
            { month "may" =
               { year "May" }
            { month "jun" =
               { year "June" }
            { month "jul" =
               { year "July" }
            { month "aug" =
               { year "Aug." }
            { month "sep" =
               { year "Sept." }
            { month "oct" =
               { year "Oct" }
            { month "nov" =
               { year "Nov." }
            { month "dec" =
               { year "Dec." }
            { year "Nomember" }
            if$}if$}if$}if$}if$}if$}if$}if$}if$}if$}if$}if$}if$}
         if$}
    if$}
  extra.label * % new in v.1.2
}
```

Abbreviations of months done according to `GOST 7.12-93` and `GOST 7.11-2004 (ISO 832:1994)`.

After this i received new error - "command `\cyra`, `\cyrb`, ... unavailable in encoding EU1". This problem caused by `hyperref` package. To resolve, I put next code just right before `\begin{document}`.

```
\newcommand{\cyr}[0]{}
\renewcommand{\cyra}[0]{а}
\renewcommand{\cyrb}[0]{б}
\renewcommand{\cyrv}[0]{в}
\renewcommand{\cyrg}[0]{г}
\renewcommand{\cyrd}[0]{д}
\renewcommand{\cyre}[0]{е}
\renewcommand{\cyryo}[0]{ё}
\renewcommand{\cyrzh}[0]{ж}
\renewcommand{\cyrz}[0]{з}
\renewcommand{\cyri}[0]{и}
\renewcommand{\cyrishrt}[0]{й}
\renewcommand{\cyrk}[0]{к}
\renewcommand{\cyrl}[0]{л}
\renewcommand{\cyrm}[0]{м}
\renewcommand{\cyrn}[0]{н}
\renewcommand{\cyro}[0]{о}
\renewcommand{\cyrp}[0]{п}
\renewcommand{\cyrr}[0]{р}
\renewcommand{\cyrs}[0]{с}
\renewcommand{\cyrt}[0]{т}
\renewcommand{\cyru}[0]{у}
\renewcommand{\cyrf}[0]{ф}
\renewcommand{\cyrh}[0]{х}
\renewcommand{\cyrc}[0]{ц}
\renewcommand{\cyrch}[0]{ч}
\renewcommand{\cyrsh}[0]{ш}
\renewcommand{\cyrshch}[0]{щ}
\renewcommand{\cyrsftsn}[0]{ь}
\renewcommand{\cyrery}[0]{ы}
\renewcommand{\cyrhrdsn}[0]{ъ}
\renewcommand{\cyrerev}[0]{э}
\renewcommand{\cyryu}[0]{ю}
\renewcommand{\cyrya}[0]{я}

\renewcommand{\CYRA}[0]{А}
\renewcommand{\CYRB}[0]{Б}
\renewcommand{\CYRV}[0]{В}
\renewcommand{\CYRG}[0]{Г}
\renewcommand{\CYRD}[0]{Д}
\renewcommand{\CYRE}[0]{Е}
\renewcommand{\CYRYO}[0]{Ё}
\renewcommand{\CYRZH}[0]{Ж}
\renewcommand{\CYRZ}[0]{З}
\renewcommand{\CYRI}[0]{И}
\renewcommand{\CYRY}[0]{Й}
\renewcommand{\CYRK}[0]{К}
\renewcommand{\CYRL}[0]{Л}
\renewcommand{\CYRM}[0]{М}
\renewcommand{\CYRN}[0]{Н}
\renewcommand{\CYRO}[0]{О}
\renewcommand{\CYRP}[0]{П}
\renewcommand{\CYRR}[0]{Р}
\renewcommand{\CYRS}[0]{С}
\renewcommand{\CYRT}[0]{Т}
\renewcommand{\CYRU}[0]{У}
\renewcommand{\CYRF}[0]{Ф}
\renewcommand{\CYRH}[0]{Х}
\renewcommand{\CYRC}[0]{Ц}
\renewcommand{\CYRCH}[0]{Ч}
\renewcommand{\CYRSH}[0]{Ш}
\renewcommand{\CYRSHCH}[0]{Щ}
\renewcommand{\CYRSFTSN}[0]{Ь}
\renewcommand{\CYRERY}[0]{Ы}
\renewcommand{\CYRHRDSN}[0]{Ъ}
\renewcommand{\CYREREV}[0]{Э}
\renewcommand{\CYRYU}[0]{Ю}
\renewcommand{\CYRYA}[0]{Я}
```

I use: linux, kile, XeLaTeX to compile and Zotero to import BiBtex (also hacked by me because it doesn't provide native russian support).

Maybe this may be optimized or done much easier but I use all this stuff less then a month.

Hope this help.

Comment: There is no need to use `\cyr...` commands with `xelatex` and `lualatex`, ie with Unicode engines for which `ugost...bst` series of bibstyles is devised. Just type Russian letters. However `gost....bst` styles need `\cyr...` commands as they are devised for legacy latex engines.

Comment: `{ year "Nomember" }` should be changed to `{ year month }`
`